# Vuetify 3 - How to change theme dynamically?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I would like to change theme dynamically. I define a `lightTheme` and `darkTheme` li

```
export default createVuetify({
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: "lightTheme",
    themes: {
      lightTheme: {
        dark: false,
        colors: {
          primary: "#ad1c3d",
          "page-header-background": "#d7d7ce",
          "page-background": "#cdcdc1",
          "table-header": "#cdcdc1",
          background: "#c0c0b5",
          "header-background": "#b5b5a6",
          "info-text": "#666660",
        },
      },
      darkTheme: {
        dark: true,
        colors: {
          primary: "#52E3C2",
          "page-header-background": "#282831",
          "page-background": "#32323E",
          "table-header": "#2e2e2e",
          background: "#3F3F4A",
          "header-background": "#4a4a59",
          "info-text": "#99999F",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I can access the theme using `this.$vuetify.theme` however I can't find how I can change the theme at runtime. The method of doing this in `Vuetify 2` is different. I can't find any examples with `Vuetify 3`.

What is the correct method of changing theme dynamically in `Vuetify 3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the documentation is incorrect. The documentation says to use

```
this.theme.global.name.value = "themeName"
```

but actually it's

```
this.theme.global.name = "themeName"
```

Comment: This isn´t true anymore. since  `theme.global.name` is readonly

Answer (score 0):

Use the `useTheme` composable provided

```
import { useTheme } from 'vuetify'

const theme = useTheme()

theme.global.name.value = 'lightTheme'
```

Source: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/